# How to run firebase in a flutter project iOS

Tags: flutter

I am new to firebase with flutter and I started very well but on the iPhone side after following all the steps and importing in the public.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.1
  firebase_core: ^1.8.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.4
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.4
```

I tried to run my app and it is taking hours on the Xcode build
I do not know what to do

Comment: Hello , Could you try running with --verbose.
Also need to check if the podfiles have downloaded yet . That might be taking time.

Comment: How do I check the pod files?

Comment: They are present under iOS/Pod.
Did you run "pod install" ?
Please confirm if the steps mentioned in link below have been followed :
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is taking too long or the app isn't even running. Please go to the ios file under project. In the IOS file go to the Podfile and uncomment the part:

```
platform : ios,'9.0'
```

or increase the target i.e '9.0' to the latest version

If that doesn't work replace the code in podfile [image] with this new code [image]

Tell me if that worked.

Comment: It's still taking ages to load and is even slowering my computer

Comment: can you share what it shows inside the console of your program? What does your app shows while you are trying to run??

Comment: It shows only this and never run

Comment: Running Xcode build...